# Did Rashi have Talmud Yerushalmi?

Tags: rashi, talmud-yerushalmi

Rashi quotes a couple of times from Yerushalmi but doesn't seem to have had regular access to it. This being from the numerous times Rishonim ask on him from it.

Comment: If I recall correctly,  as I don't have the sefer on hand, in "Shas Cohen's" sefer kerem yehoshua he brings a tradition from Rav Chaim of Volozhin, that Rashi had Yerushalmi, rather the methodology of rashi was to limit such references.

Comment: To add to @אילפא's point, Rashi's methodology is to explain each Gemara in its own terms. Rashi mostly does not discuss interpretations from other sources, even when they are relevant. When Rashi does bring in another source, it is almost always to define a word. This is true even for sources Rashi definitely had, such as Sifrei. E.g. https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Gittin.8b.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, welcome to MiYodeya!

While it seems that it as you say, i.e. Rashi had [at least occasionally access to the Jerusalem Talmud due to the large number of merchant-soldiers travelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi#:%7E:text=Because%20of%20the%20large%20number,which%20readings%20should%20be%20preferred.):

> Because of the large number of merchant-scholars who came from throughout the Jewish world to attend the great fairs in Troyes, Rashi was able to compare different manuscripts and readings in Tosefta, **Jerusalem Talmud**, Midrash, Targum, and the writings of the Geonim, and determine which readings should be preferred

At the same time, it does not seem as [if he had direct access or rather, continual ownership to a complete, actual copy of the text itself as per The Lehrhaus' article](https://thelehrhaus.com/scholarship/revival-of-the-forgotten-talmud/):

> Yerushalmi’s further spread occurred gradually. For example, **Rashi seemingly did not have access to a full copy of Yerushalmi**, while Rabbeinu Tam had at least a copy of Yerushalmi Zera’im and Moed in his library.[25]

The citation from the article is a paper: [Reiner, R. (2019) "The Yerushalmi in Rabbeinu Tam’s Library, REJ 178"](https://www.academia.edu/41603184/The_Yerushalmi_in_Rabbeinu_Tam_s_Library_REJ_178_2019_), who specifically investigates the use and spread of the Jerusalem Talmud in the Middle Ages, focusing on the grandson of Rashi.

[Others](https://jewishlink.news/rashi-insights-into-his-life-and-works/) such as Mitchell First, a columnist for the Jewish Link of New Jersey, also push this view:

> 5. Rashi rarely cited the Jerusalem Talmud. It seems that Rashi had only selections of the Jerusalem Talmud available to him.

Finally, [Grunhaus N. (2003) "The Dependence of Rabbi David Kimhi (Radak) on Rashi in His Quotation of Midrashic Traditions" paper](https://repository.yu.edu/handle/20.500.12202/4622) states in a more definitive manner:

> **For example, it is known that Rashi did not always have a complete copy of the Yerushalmi.** See M. Higger, "The Yerushalmi Quotations in Rashi," in Rashi Anniversary Volume, pp. 191-192; L. Ginzberg...

> Some passages attributed to the Yerushalmi by Rashi are not found in the
> Yerushalmi extant today. Just as Rashi's talmudic library was incomplete, so too his library of midrashic texts may have been lacking. For a complete study of the rabbinic works used by Rashi, see Y. L. ha-Cohen Maimon...

So while there might not be universally hard and absolute proof, evidence does indeed indicate that Rashi did not have continual access to a full copy of the Jerusalem Talmud, but he did indeed read it occasionally (or at least, fragments of it) due to a large number of travelling merchant-soldiers in the region. This seems to be the scholarly view on the matter at least.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome Dovid!

An answer and also food for thought and further research.

First, this might be nitpicking, but even an admittedly cursory [search for the word **ירושלמי** in רש"י על ש"ס in Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99&tab=text&tpathFilters=Mishnah%20Commentary%2FRishonim%20on%20Mishnah%2FRashi%7CTalmud%20Commentary%2FRishonim%20on%20Talmud%2FRashi&tvar=1&tsort=chronological&svar=1&ssort=relevance) will yield **about 40 occurrences** where Rashi references the Talmud Yerushalmi (*see full list below*).  So it's difficult to stick with saying Rashi only quotes Yerushalmi "a couple of times" or "a few times" or "several times" as has been mentioned elsewhere.  Even "rarely" would have to be considered a relative term since one would have to define what rarely means.

The following list also *attempts* to eliminate false positives from that search such as where:

- the word ירושלמי doesn't refer to Talmud Yerushalmi at all
- there are Talmud Yerushalmi quotes from "Rashis" in masechtos that don't necessarily have actual Rashi (such as Nedarim, Nazir and some others - if you see any other questionable ones in the list, please take this factor into account)
- a plethora of לשון\לישנא ירושלמי quotes in מסכת תמורה where Rashi is likely not referring to the Talmud Yerushalmi
- I put parentheses around times where Rashi references the Yerushalmi in general without bringing a direct quote

**The following list seems to indicate that Rashi had access to at least 10 masechtos of the Yerushalmi: ברכות, שביעית, תרומות, ביכורים, שבת, פסחים, יומא, מגילה, קידושין, סנהדרין**

- **משנה אבות ב:ד**
  : שנינו **בגמרא ירושלמי** על תמיד של שחר שקרב בארבע שעות
- **משנה אבות ב:ח**
  בקשו רחמים על העובר הזה שיהיה חכם. **בגמרא ירושלמי**
- **ברכות ב. ד"ה עד סוף האשמורה הראשונה**
  והכי תניא בבריי' **בברכות ירושלמי**.
- **ברכות ד: ד"ה זה הסומך**
  : ואמרי' **בברכות ירושלמי** (פ"א) מי שאינו סומך גאולה לתפלה
- **ברכות יא. ד"ה מתני' בשחר מברך שתים**
  : כדאמר **בברכות ירושלמי** שבע ברכות הללו
- **שבת
  לד. ד"ה
  עבד איהו נמי הכי**
  : ....וציינו למקום הקבר הכי מפרש בפסיקתא דפרשת העומר **ובסדר זרעים ירושלמי**
  (שביעית ט)
- **שבת ס. ד"ה בזמן שאין ברגלו מכה** : **בש"ס ירושלמי** מפרש דלא ליחשדיה
- **שבת צב. ד"ה מתני' שכן משא בני קהת**
  : ובשם רבינו יצחק בר יהודה מצאתי שאמר בשם רב האי שמפורש **בהש"ס ירושלמי**
- **שבת קל: ד"ה שמותי הוא**
  : ...**ובתלמוד ירושלמי** מפ' שמותי הוא מתלמידי שמאי היה
  (שביעית ט)
- **שבת קנג: ד"ה ותורם את שאינו שלו** : ....שיש לו לב להתנדב **בהש"ס ירושלמי**:
  (תרומות א:א)
- **ר"ה יד. ד"ה איכא בינייהו**
  : ומפרש טעמיה **בתלמוד ירושלמי** א"ר מנא מכיון שמנע מהן מים שלשים יום
  (שביעית ב:ו)
- **יומא כח: ד"ה ואיבעית אימא האי דקאי אארעא**
  : ומצינו **בתלמוד ירושלמי** (פ"ג ה"א) כדי להזכיר זכות אבות מזכירין חברון
- **יומא מז. ד"ה לא ראו קורות ביתי כו'** : ראיתי **בהש"ס ירושלמי** כל כבודה בת מלך פנימה
- **יומא נב. ד"ה טרקסין** : לשון פנים וחוץ הוא כך ראיתי **בתלמוד ירושלמי**
- **יומא פז: ד"ה נחית קמיה דרבא** : ...ולשון נעילה פליגי אמוראי **בברכו' ירושלמי** חד אמר נעילת שערי שמים
- **סוכה מז: ד"ה טעונין קרבן** : להביא עמהם שלמים **ובהש"ס ירושלמי** יליף מושמחת בכל הטוב
- **תענית כו. ד"ה נעילת שערים** – מפורש **בברכות ירושלמי** בפרק תפלת השחר אימתי נעילה יש אומרים נעילת שערי מקדש
- **מגילה ה. ד"ה וחגיגה**
  : **ובגמרא ירושלמי** מפרש דהא דלא עבדינן ליה בשבת
- **מגילה כט. ד"ה ברביעית החודש הזה לכם** : ששם פרשת הפסח **ובש"ס ירושלמי** גרסינן אמר ר' חמא בדין הוא
- **(חגיגה י. ד"ה אפילו מש"ס לש"ס** : **מש"ס ירושלמי** לש"ס בבלי שהוא עמוק כדאמרינן בסנהדרין (דף כד.) במחשכים הושיבני כמתי עולם זו הש"ס של בבל
  )
- **סוטה טז. ד"ה והלכה בכל דבר**
  : **ובמסכת קידושין ירושלמי** מצאתי משנה זו דר' ישמעאל
- **סוטה מא: ד"ה מאימת דמתחיל מועד**
  : והאי טעמא מפרש **בגמ' ירושלמי** (פ"א) במס' מגילה
- **(סוטה מט: ד"ה לשון סורסי** : קרוב הוא ללשון ארמי ואומר אני שזה לשון **גמרת ירושלמי** ואומות העולם קורין אותו לינג"א שוריי"א (שפה סורית)
  )
- **גיטין ס: ד"ה ופרשת פרה אדומה**
  : והכי אמרינן **במסכת מגילה ירושלמי** באחד בניסן הוקם המשכן
- **קידושין לא: ד"ה ומביאו לעוה"ב**
  : **ובגמרת ירושלמי** גרס מעשה בשניהם
- **קידושין סט: ד"ה התרשתא** : ....**ובגמרת ירושלמי** נמצא שעל שם שהיה משקה למלך
- **ב"ק קיז: ד"ה ואי לא הואיל וחליף שעתא**
  : ועוד אמרי' **בברכות ירושלמי** דפגע ביה ההוא גברא
- **סנהדרין ה: ד"ה רבי חייא חזייה**
  : **ובמס' שביעית ירושלמי** בפרק שלש ארצות מצאתי בההוא עובדא
- **מכות יא. ד"ה שכרה דוד שיתין** : ...**ובגמרת ירושלמי** (סנהדרין פ"י) מצינו תימוליוס של בית המקדש והוא יסוד בלשון יוני
- **מכות יא. ד"ה קפא תהומא** : ...**בגמרת ירושלמי** (שם) שמצא שם חרס שהגביה קולו
- **זבחים לז. ד"ה תרי תנאי אליבא דר' ישמעאל**
  : ...אבל פסח פוטר את הזבח **ובפסחים ירושלמי** האי טעמא אמר בה
- **זבחים נז. ד"ה בכרם** : ת"ח יושבין שורות ככרם כך מפורש **בברכות ירושלמי**
- **זבחים ק"ה. ד"ה דנקיטי לה בבקולסי**
  : ...בקולסי בלשון **הש"ס ירושלמי** מקל
- **מנחות נח. ד"ה לעטר בכורים אתו**
  : ...אמרינן **בתלמוד ירושלמי** דהאי קרבן שלמים הוא כתיב הכא ושמחת בכל הטוב
- **מנחות ק. ד"ה מתתיא בן שמואל**
  : **ובתלמוד ירושלמי** נמצא שלפיכך היה אומר עד שבחברון ביום הכפורים
- **נדה ח. ד"ה ואמר רבי אלעזר הלכה כרבי אליעזר** : **בברכות ירושלמי**

Due to the wide sweep of quotes above, it appears that Rashi had at least some significant access to the Yerushalmi during his lifetime whether hearing from others orally or even in handwritten form.  *See answers posted by others here as to how that access might have manifested itself and how complete or incomplete it might have been*.

Comment: 2k pages of talmud * 2 sides * 10 comments = ~40000 comments. 40/40000=0.01% that's pretty fairly called "rare"

Comment: The ref to shabbat 92a is of Rashi quoting someone else quoting yerushalmi so it doesn't show he had any access (on the contrary)